# Renaming file with filepicker.io

Tags: filepicker.io

Here is my use case: the user will click a "save" link and will be presented with a filepicker.export() dialog, choose a location and name and save a file. Here's the exotic part: I won't have the file yet at that time. It needs to be downloaded first with a GET request, and then stored in filepicker. I won't know which file to start downloading until the user clicks "save".

This can be dealt with by first downloading the file when the user clicks "save", and only then displaying the filepicker.export() dialog. However, I find this cumbersome, since the user will have to wait for the download to finish to be able to choose a filename and location.

It would be much better to allow the user to first make their choice, for example "Dropbox/image.png", and store some sort of placeholder while the download is running: "Dropbox/image.png.part". Later, when the download finishes, I could write the data to the file and rename it to "Dropbox/image.png".

Here are my questions:

1. Is it possible to append ".part" to the filename that the user chose in the filepicker.export() call?
2. More importantly, while I know how to write to the file when the download is done, is there any way to rename it? I tried creating a new fpfile object with the same filepicker URL and a different filename, the new filename was ignored (though the write succeeded).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation would be to first call `filepicker.export` call on an empty file and allow the user to specify both the name of the file they would like and the location in their cloud storage. When the `filepicker.export` call finishes, it will pass an FPFile into the callback. From there, you can download any necessary contents you need and do a `filepicker.write` to save the contents to the location selected by the user.

There shouldn't be any need to rename the file, as the user has already provided the name they want to save the file under during the filepicker.export() call.

Comment: I just thought it would be a little weird for the user to see the file there, ready and available, but realize it's empty when they open it. I guess I'll go with this way for lack of a better one. Thanks for your answer!